# Pandas create boolean column based on whether 3 column values are all negative or all positive

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, boolean-logic

I have the following data frame,

```
       f1           f2      f3  f4  f5          f6          f7
0   -0.004446   59.763107   x0  0   60.029999   59.160000   -0.014493
1   -0.003414   113.212220  x1  0   113.599998  113.650002  0.000440
2   -0.013123   36.435513   x2  1   36.919998   36.889999   -0.000813
3   0.003558    68.854090   x3  0   68.420158   68.410179   -0.000146
4   -0.006840   23.021446   x4  0   23.180000   23.100000   -0.003451
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
145 0.000724    253.113110  x5  1   252.929993  247.210007  -0.022615
146 0.006567    128.236680  x6  0   127.400002  127.059998  -0.002669
147 -0.009016   610.079200  x7  1   615.630005  605.369995  -0.016666
148 -0.011290   165.173920  x8  0   167.059998  158.300003  -0.052436
149 0.021474    358.496370  x9  0   350.959991  343.329987  -0.021740
```

Basically, for column `f4`, treat 0 as a negative or False and 1 as a positive or True.

If values from columns `f1`, `f4` and `f7` are all negative or all positive, the test column should return true for that row, else it should return false.

I want to create new column called 'test' that will say `True` or `False` based on my conditions. If in any cases, one of them don't match (either not all true or not all false), it will show `False`.

I can make the following code work with 2 columns,

```
df.loc[:,'test'] = df['f1'].ge(0).eq(df['f4'])
```

and it works fine.

However, if I try to chain it to add the `f7` column like this,

```
df.loc[:,'test'] = df['f1'].ge(0).eq(df['f4']).eq(df['f7'].ge(0))
```

the results are wrong.

I want the test column to look like this,

```
       f1           f2      f3  f4  f5          f6          f7         test
0   -0.004446   59.763107   x0  0   60.029999   59.160000   -0.014493  True
1   -0.003414   113.212220  x1  0   113.599998  113.650002  0.000440   False
2   -0.013123   36.435513   x2  1   36.919998   36.889999   -0.000813  False
3   0.003558    68.854090   x3  0   68.420158   68.410179   -0.000146  False
4   -0.006840   23.021446   x4  0   23.180000   23.100000   -0.003451  True
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
145 0.000724    253.113110  x5  1   252.929993  247.210007  -0.022615  False
146 0.006567    128.236680  x6  0   127.400002  127.059998  -0.002669  False
147 -0.009016   610.079200  x7  1   615.630005  605.369995  -0.016666  False
148 -0.011290   165.173920  x8  0   167.059998  158.300003  -0.052436  True
149 0.021474    358.496370  x9  0   350.959991  343.329987  -0.021740  False
```

How do I get the code to work the way I want it to?

Comment: Can you try `df[['f1', 'f4', 'f7']].ge(0).sum(axis=1).isin([0, 3])`?

Comment: @Marat that wouldn’t work, because f4 has to be 1 right not greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: Then, `(df['f4'] + df[['f1', 'f7']].ge(0)).sum(axis=1).isin([0, 3])`

Comment: @Marat everything just comes out as true now

Comment: I checked your sum formula, everything comes out as NaN

Comment: right, bad parenthesis placement. Should be `(df['f4'] + df[['f1', 'f7']].ge(0).sum(axis=1)).isin([0, 3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because
if f1 and f4 are negative, the first two comparisons will return positive, therefore chaining third will return false.

I think what you are trying to do is negative of XOR operation.
Code below will give you the idea.

```
table = np.array(
   [[-5.5,0,-6.6],
    [-5.5,0, 6.6],
    [-5.5,1,-6.6],
    [-5.5,1, 6.6],
    [ 5.5,0,-6.6],
    [ 5.5,0, 6.6],
    [ 5.5,1,-6.6],
    [ 5.5,1, 6.6]]
)

pd_table = pd.DataFrame(table)

df = pd_table
and_all = df[0].ge(0) & df[1] & df[2].ge(0)
or_all = df[0].ge(0) | df[1] | df[2].ge(0)

print(and_all.eq(or_all))
```

The output will be like this:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: hey it didn't work, I got a case where f1 is -ve, f4 is 1 and f7 is -ve and it comes out true

Comment: Sorry, I didn't verify the code I wrote last time and it was incorrect. I edited the answer.  Hope this will help

Comment: Could you explain why you use both abs and or ? I thought it should just be and

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by abs. '&' and '|' are element-wise AND and OR each, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another way of doing this, but in my case, I wrote down the truth table and tried to fit it in.

Comment: Sorry I mean and and or

Comment: Yeah I don’t get why you chose and equals or, never seen this before

Comment: Now that I think of it, I first came up with the idea of min(values) == max(values) where T=1, F=0. But since it's boolean anyway I thought AND and OR would be enough.